# Google Play Store suddenly popping up and suggesting apps in development

Tags: google-play-store

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 edge. For the last 3 weeks, I constantly get pop-ups (10-15 times a day) from the Google Play Store, suggesting apps that are in development.

[image: screenshot showing an unreleased app on Play Store]

It happens when I am doing everything from email, searches, playing games, on a call, and even when I am using a hands-free app in my car.

I have turned off notifications, but nothing has stopped it.

How to stop this annoying and distracting behavior?

Comment: Google Play Store doesn't do this. It's some app that you installed. Try detecting which app(s) are responsible using apps [from this list](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en-IN&source=hp&biw=&bih=&q=apps+ad+detector&btnG=Google+Search&gbv=1). They won't tell you which app is doing that. You would need to uninstall those apps

Comment: Maybe that is incorrect:  Just read this:  Google just bought admob.

Comment: When did detection, ADMOB is on almost  every single app that I have. Most likely causing all the pop ups related to GOOGLE PLAY STORE

Comment: I am not aware of that (Google buying admob) but on my device(s) it doesn't happen and neither has anybody reported it here. Admob is pretty much there in such apps but linking it therefore to Play Store isn't conclusive

Comment: Google bought Admob years ago. And as @beeshyams already pointed out, Playstore doesn't do that *on its own.* But any app can call an intent to have playstore pop up with a given app – which is what's happening here. So you've got some bad app(le) in your basket. And I very much doubt this has to do with Admob. Rather looks like Appflyer or something like that.